# handleChange is not working for formik inside a modal

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

i am new to react and i was trying to make render a form inside a modal from antd but my handeChange is not working.
this normally works if i write everything inside the modal but i want to know how this can be done by using a different component and by using formik

```
const InnerForm=({
                     submitted,
                     loading,
                     errors,
                     handleSubmit,
                     handleChange,
                     values,
                     modalCancel
                 })=>
    (
        <Form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormItem>
                <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                       placeholder="email"
                       onChange={handleChange}
                       name={"email"}
                />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
                <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                       type="password"
                       placeholder="Password"
                       onChange={handleChange}
                       name={"password"}
                />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
                <Button className={'button_margin'} onClick={modalCancel} type={"primary"}><Icon type="left"/>Go back</Button>
                <Button className={'button_margin'} type={"primary"}>Submit</Button>
            </FormItem>
        </Form>

    );

class App extends Component{
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            is_authenticated: false,
            application_status_modal_visible: false,
        }
    }
handleChange =(event)=>{
        const {name,value}=event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
        console.log("handle change works");
   };
    handleSubmit=(values)=>{
    console.log(values);
    };
    modalCancel=()=>{
        this.setState({application_status_modal_visible:false})
    };
render(){
return(
<Modal
                    title="Login"
                    visible={application_status_modal_visible}
                    footer={null}
                   >
                    <Formik onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            render={formikProps =>
                                <InnerForm
                                    modelCancel={this.modalCancel}
                                    {...formikProps}
                                />
                            }/>
                </Modal>)
}
}

export default connect()(App)
```

i expect this output {email:"abc@gmail.com",password:"1234567"}

Comment: the question I would ask is: why are you using formik if you have your `handleChange` function? that being said.... your `Input` component, would be good to see it. And since you are using your external `handleChange` (formik does this ish) you would want to pass your values from state into `InputForm` and then into the `Input` component

Comment: the reason i am using formik is to validate the input that is being entered,and about handleChange i m passing the formikprops as well,so handleChange will also be props for the InnerForm,can u suggest some different way to deal with this@delis

Comment: Haven't had much time...if you still need help on this, I'd look at it soon...

Comment: What modal are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `<Formik>` component does not accept a prop `handleChange`; it passes a render prop called `handleChange` and you can use that in a custom way, like so (I am not listing all the other required props):

```
<Formik>
  ({ handleChange }) => (
    <input
     onChange={
      (e) => { 
        /* custom stuff */ 
        handleChange(e)}
       } 
    />
   )
</Formik>
```